# PHP assign concat value to variable

Tags: php

i want to concat two variable and assign it to another variable

```
$name = Drew;
$counter = $counter + 1;
$num_padded = sprintf("%05d", $counter);
$new_padded_value = $name . $num_padded;
echo $new_padded_value;
```

Im expecting it to echo Drew.00001
its not working. how can I achieve this.

Comment: By learning the basics of the syntax …? Unless you have a constant by the name of `Drew` defined, that obviously must be quoted.

Comment: ahh forgot that part..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a string dot between the vars. The dot that you used is just the string concatenation operator; it doesn't actually add a dot to the string result. Change:

```
$new_padded_value = $name . $num_padded;
```

To:

```
$new_padded_value = "$name.$num_padded";
```

Also change:

```
$name = Drew;
```

To:

```
$name = "Drew";
```